# What plant/gems are these?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

What gems/plant is this?

I picked up this branch in a forest past winter. The white gems(?) are still intanct after three month, without water provisioning. Location: northern Italy.
[image: gems]

---

Here is another pic of the inside, with scale. I have no image of the plant[image: inner detail]

Comment: Are the gems fruit, with seeds inside?

Comment: A close up to gems and wood would help. Also a photo of complete brush could give hints.

Comment: I have cut it open one of the white  spheres and it is indeed an hollow sphere, so probably a dry fruit (shell is though to break)

Answer (score 1):

I think these are catkins from one of the [Salix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pussy_willow) species. Usually they are sold in late winter as spring announcers and retain their appearance for a few months.